Getting the warning "Tried to allowlist unknown rule references: ['L100']" when creating custom rule
I am trying to create Sqlfluff custom rules for my team, currently the standard rules are working correctly, but when i try to run the customized rule it results in an error indicating that the custom rule is not detected by the linter
Does anyone know how to reference a new custom rule in my .sqlfluff file? I’ve created one to evaluate if it works:
from sqlfluff.core.rules.base import BaseRule, LintResult
from sqlfluff.core.parser import KeywordSegment, RawSegment

class Rule_L100(BaseRule):

    def _eval(self, segment, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(segment, RawSegment):
            if segment.raw_upper in ["LIKE", "ILIKE"]:
                prev_segment = segment.get_direct_parent().segments[-2]
                if prev_segment.raw_upper != "COALESCE" and prev_segment.raw_upper != "IFNULL":
                    return LintResult(anchor=segment, description="LIKE/ILIKE without NULL handling.")
        return None

The file is located at sqlfluff_custom_rules/L100.py.
My templater is Jinja, and here is my .sqlfluff file configuration:
[sqlfluff]
templater = jinja

rules = AL01, AL02, AL03, AL04, AL05, AL06, AL07, AM01, AM02, AM03, AM04, AM05,
        AM06, AM07, CP01, CP02, CP03, CP04, CP05, CV01, CV02, CV03, CV04, CV05,
        CV06, CV07, CV08, CV09, CV10, CV11, JJ01, LT01, LT02, LT03, LT04, LT05,
        LT06, LT07, LT08, LT09, LT10, LT11, LT12, LT13, RF01, RF02, RF03,
        RF04, RF05, RF06, ST01, ST02, ST03, ST04, ST05, ST06, ST08, TQ01

[sqlfluff:rules]
custom_rules = custom_rules::Rule_L100

I’m running the command:
sqlfluff lint models/intermediate/any_model.sql --dialect redshift --rules L100

But I’m getting the warning: WARNING Tried to allowlist unknown rule references: ['L100']
Could someone help me with this? I’ve searched through the documentation and other sources, but there’s no clear answer on how to implement custom rules in SQLFluff, and some relevant links seem to be broken.
I’m also wondering if this issue might be because custom rules aren’t available unless they’re implemented as a plugin. Does that make more sense?

You're correct that custom rules can only be implemented as plugins. SQLFluff uses pluggy as it's plugin engine, which relies on the python packaging index to discover installed plugins. You don't need to publish your plugin publicly for this to work, you only need to be able to install it locally (i.e. pip install -e /path/to/my/local/plugin). For the necessary structure your plugin has to have there's an example plugin in the SQLFluff GitHub repository.
There's now a guide for this on the SQLFluff docs: https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/latest/guides/setup/developing_custom_rules.html
